# passing params with react native navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two component Settings,LocationSettings.Settings is the root component ,Is it possible to pass params from LocationSettings to settings when press back on header left.I'm using react navigation version 2.

Comment: Write and bind the function that sets params as state in the root component, pass it to the child and run it there as a prop.

Comment: `this.props.navigation.setParams({otherParam: 'Updated!'})`
Doc:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams